# Implementing datatable plugin in codeigniter

Tags: json, codeigniter, datatable

I am using jquery data-table plugin in codeigniter with smarty template.For the time being I am writing code(queries too) in controller. I am getting the required data before using json_encode function to pass json data to ajax. Datatables view is not loading.No error showing in console. Json data is not passed to view.
Any help will be appreciated..

```
function jobseekers_list(){

    $this->CI = & get_instance();
    $this->DB = &$this->CI->db;

    $aColumns = array('id', 'fname', 'email');

    // DB table to use
    $sTable = 'users';  

    $this->DB->select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS '.str_replace(' , ', ' ', implode(', ', $aColumns)), false)->where('user_type', 1);
    $rResult = $this->DB->get($sTable);

    $this->DB->select('FOUND_ROWS() AS found_rows');
    $iFilteredTotal = $this->DB->get()->row()->found_rows;

    $iTotal = $this->DB->count_all($sTable);

    // Output
    $output = array(
        'sEcho' => intval($sEcho),
        'iTotalRecords' => $iTotal,
        'iTotalDisplayRecords' => $iFilteredTotal,
        'aaData' => array()
    );

    foreach($rResult->result_array() as $aRow)
    {
        $output['aaData'][] = $aRow;
    }

    echo json_encode($output);
```

}

here is my view file...jquery 1.8.2 is included in header file

```
{include file="header.tpl"}

<link href='//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="jsgrid" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>

    </tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>

{literal}<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#jsgrid').dataTable({
        "Processing": true,
        "ServerSide": true,
        "Ajax": "admin_users/jobseekers_list"

    });
}); 
</script>{/literal}

{include file="footer.tpl"}
```

Comment: Do you know if you get any response from your ajax call?

Comment: What do you get if you access the URL to admin_users/jobseekers_list in your browser?

Comment: @JimboSlice....nothing is displaying on page

Comment: @jimboSlice...is there any restriction on the number of columns or order of columns in Datatables ?

Comment: hm, maybe a PHP error then. Have you error reporting turned on? Check in your index.php

Comment: there is no restriction on number of columns / order.

Comment: I think the best approach is to first make sure admin_users/jobseekers_list is working as planned. Before debugging the datatables.